# HTTP request - Request module - 302 redirect location containing html escaped character

Tags: node.js, request

I'm using request module to send an http post request to a server which respond http 302 with the location redirect url "strangely" encoded:

```
'https&#58%3B//xxx.xxx.com&#63%3Bsrcext%3Dvalue&amp%3Berl=rrf
```

When i do the same request in chrome, chrome show me the location redirect URL as:

```
"https://xxx.xxx.com?srcext=value&erl=rrf"
```

Curl give me the same "response" as request module:

```
'https&#58%3B//xxx.xxx.com&#63%3Bsrcext%3Dvalue&amp%3Berl=rrf
```

Request options "followRedirect/followAllRedirects" fail to follow the link, curl option -L fail to follow the link.
No problem in chrome

I know i can apply "by hand" a method to decode the url "properly" but this is tricky as some parameters included need to stay encoded.

Is there an option in curl or request that i miss to directly "decode" the url and make the redirection option works ?

Thanks in advance

=========== EDIT =======
for request i'm using

```
request({
  method:                           "POST",
            url:                                "https://balbalab.com",
            headers: {
                'Cookie':                       "XXXXX",
                'Accept-Encoding':              'gzip, deflate, fr',
                'Accept-Language':              'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
                'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':    '1',
                'User-Agent':                   'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/55.0.2883.87 Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36',
                'Content-Type':                 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Accept':                       'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
                'Cache-Control':                'no-cache',
                'Connection':                   'keep-alive',
                "Pragma":                       "no-cache",
                "Content-Type":                 "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

            },
            gzip:                               true,
            form:                               formFields,

            followRedirect:                     true,
            followAllRedirects:                 true

}
```

for curl i'm using:

```
curl -X POST "https://url1.url1.com" \
-H 'Accept-Encoding:                gzip, deflate, fr' \
-H 'Accept-Language:                fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7' \
-H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:  1' \
-H 'User-Agent:                     Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/55.0.2883.87 Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36' \
-H 'Content-Type:               application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-H 'Accept:                         text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
-H 'Cache-Control:              no-cache' \
-H 'Connection:                     keep-alive' \
-H "Pragma:                         no-cache" \
-H "Content-Type:               application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-d 'xx=ff' \
-L
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you parse the URL? It seems like you are missing url-encoded flag in your parser.

Comment: i didn't get you, could you be more specific ?

Comment: how did you get the redirect url: 
```
https&#58%3B//xxx.xxx.com&#63%3Bsrcext%3Dvalue&amp%3Berl=rrf 
```

was it by: 
```
res.headers.location
```

Comment: yes, in res.headers.location